# Creating new set of columns in a dataframe in R from existing columns with names in a vector

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with fields x,y,A,B like this:

```
d <- data.frame(x=seq(1,26),y=seq(1,26,by=2),A=LETTERS[seq(1,26)],
                          B=letters[seq(1,26)])
```

and a vector of columnames:

```
colnames <- c('A','B')
```

I would like to add extra fields to the dataframe A_mod and B_mod with values based on a function which processes the value of resp A and B of the same row.

So I would like to end up with a dataframe with fields x, y, A, B and A_mod and B_mod. The values of A_mod and B_mod are calculated by resp

```
   A_mod = tolower(A)
```

and

```
   B_mod = toupper(B) for instance (just a mock example).
```

How can I do that without explicitly naming the columns `A`, `B` and `A_mod` and `B_mod`, but instead use the vector colnames. In reality my dataframe has 30 columns, so writing all by hand is tedious (and the amount of columns will increase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
d[paste0(colnames,'_mod')] <- lapply(d[colnames], tolower)
head(d,3)
#   x y A B A_mod B_mod
#1 1 1 A a     a     a
#2 2 3 B b     b     b
#3 3 5 C c     c     c
```

Comment: It doesn't completely comply with my sample, but my sample was wrong, not the answer :) I do need to apply the same function to each column so this will work. Thanks.